# Mingw -- Conflicting types for function due to previous declaration

Tags: c, mingw

To start off, I don't get this issue when I compile/"make" the code on a Linux machine which I connect to remotely. I'm experiencing it only on my Windows laptop with Mingw installed -- which I believe is causing the issue.

```
$ make
gcc -c parser.c
parser.c:34:7: error: conflicting types for 'gets'
   34 | char* gets(char *buf, int max)
      |       ^~~~
In file included from parser.h:4,
                 from parser.c:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:709:41: note: previous declaration of 'gets' was here
  709 | _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  char * gets (char *);
      |                                         ^~~~
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'parser.o' failed
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1
```

Here's the gets() code as requested:

```
char* gets(char *buf, int max)
{
  int i, cc;
  char c;

  for(i=0; i+1 < max; ){
    cc = read(0, &c, 1);
    if(cc < 1) break;
    //c = getchar();
    buf[i++] = c;
    
    if(c == '\n' || c == '\r') 
        break;
  }
  
  buf[i] = '\0';
  return buf;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this without changing the gets function name? Thank you sm

Comment: @anastaciu I'm not. I don't think it's a problem in the code since I have no issue running it in a Linux machine.

Comment: The `gets` function has *officially* been removed from the **C** standard (but some compilers still include it in their implementation of the standard library). In **C++** it was *deprecated* in the C++11 standard and [removed in C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets). Are you, perhaps, using different standards on the two platforms? (That is, make sure that you are using C++14 or later.)

Comment: Also, can you clarify whether you are using C++ or C. The line `gcc -c parser.c` looks to me like you're invoking the C compiler on a C source. Maybe you want `g++ -c parser.cpp -std=c++14` ??

Comment: @alee, it wasn't likely to be the issue since in gcc `gets` is available without the `std` namespace, but it could be some crazy conflict, in any case, it's weird since your gets has 2 arguments, it should shouldn't conflict with library `gets` which for some reason has not been removed from gcc even though it has been removed both from C and C++ standard.

Comment: @anastaciu `gets` taking two parameters would too conflict with `gets` taking one parameter if the code is compiled as C and not C++ (as seems likely). C of course doesn't have a concept of overloading.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm using C++. I'm not sure how to check for the C++ standard on Windows or if it's possible because Windows doesn't come with a C++ compiler and its libraries. My ability to compile C++ and C comes entirely from Mingw

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, IDK, the tag is C++, it would be a logical explanation though.

Comment: @alee, you would use g++ instead of gcc, mingW provides it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I believe that its compiling correctly because it works on Linux :\. The code with 'gets' and the Makefile was also provided for an assignment so

Comment: It's a long time since I used MingW or any of the GNU mainline stuffs, but `gcc` is, IIRC, for **C** only and, as @anastaciu says (and I hinted at), you need `g++` for **C++**.

Comment: My bad -- my files are C files. I've edited the tags. I've verified that the Makefile uses gcc. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: Do you redeclare `gets` in your own code? Can you show us the code?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've edited the post to include it

Comment: C doesn't support function overloading, you can't have 2 functions with the same name. There's a standard function called `gets` (it was supposed to be removed, but apparently your compiler still has it), so you can't name your own funciton `gets`.

Comment: Probably the easiest way forward is to give your version of `gets` a different name, so it doesn't conflict with the library-provided `gets`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works on Linux's gcc because [the `gets` function was removed](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JYukqwCUl4t3ChGU), as it should, since it was deprecated in the C99 standard and removed with C11.

For some reason the Windows MingW distribution still maintains `gets` and because of that you have a redefinition problem.

So unfortunately you can't use that function name, unless you remove it by hand from `stdio.h`, as C doesn't allow for function overloading.

[Running sample on Linux gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BEm0CZuRVEXC3apo)

[Running sample on Windows gcc](https://rextester.com/LMP68986)

Comment: Yup :\. I ended up removing Mingw entirely and installing Cygwin instead.

Comment: @alee, good move, renaming the function would have been easier though.

Comment: I think an important point to add is that, since this is `C` and not `C++` it's impossible to overload the function, which would've been fine as OP is not redefining `gets(char*)`

Comment: @alee Did you do that for the sole reason of freeing the name `gets`? I suggest researching the difference between those two things and making an educated choice.

Comment: @AlexShirley, you're right, I added a note, I will not mention C++ since this is a question about C and people here don't take that kindly ;).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I did it because the code defining 'gets' was provided for a project, and I'm not supposed to change it. I think using Cygwin would save me from similar issues for future projects.

Comment: @alee Yep, if you can't change the code, it's probably the right choice. I would avoid it for new projects though, its primary purpose is running code that was originally written for Linux in a non-portable manner (heavy use of POSIX) on Windows.

Comment: Moving from MinGW back to Cygwin doesn't seem like a step forward. See my solution using a simple #define to easily work around the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the `gets()` function is already defined in `stdio.h`.

One trick you can do is put something like this:

```
#define gets MY_gets
```

before your definition of the `gets()` function.

That way you are actually defining a `MY_gets()` function which causes no conflict. And when you call `gets()` later on in your code you are actually calling `MY_gets()`.

If you define `gets()` in a header file you should include `stdio.h` first and then put `#define gets MY_gets` before the declaration of `gets()` in the header file.

Though I don't see why you want to refine this function if it already exists.
It makes more sense to only define it if needed and surround the function with something like `#ifndef HAVE_GETS` and `endif` where `HAVE_GETS` should be defined based on tests done in the configure/build system.